# VS2008 - Can't remove project configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2008, solution, buildconfiguration, vcproj

I have a Windows Mobile/Pocket PC project in Visual Studio 2008 SP1.  I have tried to remove an old build configuration "ReleaseCN3" from the solution using the Configuration Manager.  I run the Configuration Manager, click on Edit, then highlight the "ReleaseCN3" configuration and click Remove.  The configuration is removed from the list, but if it does not appear to be removed from the solution or project.  I have tried restarting Visual Studio after making changes, but the old configuration still remains.  This project was migrated over using the Upgrade Wizard from eMbedded Visual C++ 4 to Visual Studio 2005 to Visual Studio 2008.

Are there any tools to cleanup a Visual Studio 2008 SLN/VCP file?  I looked at the files in Notepad and saw a number of old (no longer used) configurations in both files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually edit them in Notepad.